# Stack Trace for the Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, stack-trace, jvisualvm

We have installed "IBM SCM Adapter for ClearCase" plugin in our Eclipse environment.

We are encountering some errors while "checking out" files from ClearCase on some eclipse instances, and the plugin works fine on some other eclipse instances. We could not identify the real problem as the plugin prints very minor information on logs. Plugin's source code is not available so that we could debug.

Is it possible to see the Stack Trace (along with the actual method arguments) using some Java monitoring tool?

I am using JvisualVM, and could see the Stack Trace of main thread, but it's not showing the actual arguments that are getting passed to the problem causing methods.

The same plugin behaves differently on identical eclipse installations, we need to identify the cause.

Comment: Can't you just open a ticket with the vendor (IBM)?

Comment: I can, but it's working somewhere and not working somewhere. May be, the issue exists our side. Anyway, we will open a ticket, but that's a general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible browsing the heap dumps. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/heapdump.html